# Trying to get a lighter color from hex value

Tags: javascript

My hex value is stored like this:

```
var details = (swatches.DarkVibrant.getHex());
```

I would like to get another variable to store a lighter version of that color but I do not know how to implement it in the options I found, I found this one for example:

```
function ColorLuminance(hex, lum) {
  // validate hex string
  hex = String(hex).replace(/[^0-9a-f]/gi, '');
  if (hex.length < 6) {
    hex = hex[0] + hex[0] + hex[1] + hex[1] + hex[2] + hex[2];
  }
  lum = lum || 0;
  // convert to decimal and change luminosity
  var rgb = "#",
    c, i;
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    c = parseInt(hex.substr(i * 2, 2), 16);
    c = Math.round(Math.min(Math.max(0, c + (c * lum)), 255)).toString(16);
    rgb += ("00" + c).substr(c.length);
  }
  return rgb;
}
```

How do I pass my details var into the function to get a ligher version of my color?

Comment: Please show your effort. Posting someone else's example and asking for a solution is not enough.

Comment: Where is your `getHex` implementation?

Comment: In hex code the 3 pairs after # represents the intensity of the colors Red, Green & Blue. All 3 '00' means no color is available so it is black. All 3 'FF' means all color is full, which represents white. If you want to lighten a color - just add a small(but same) number in all three of them. For example to lighten up #A5BFD4 by 3 pints, you can add 3 in all of them: #(A5+3)(BF+3)(D4+3) = #A8C2D7. This is the basic, you can create your own or verify if the searched function is Ok by this rule.